# Search columns for keywords and match only the first substrings found

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

below is an example table that shows what I'm hoping to achieve. I have the column "text" that provides comments and I would like to add a new column called "searchBrand" which returns a category based on the search of substring keywords within "text".

| text | searchBrand |
| --- | --- |
| The M3 is quick! | BMW |
| Some would say the Prius is economical, but others like the M3 for its speed | Toyota |
| Who likes the focus? | Ford |

I created a simple dictionary that shows the substrings I'm looking for as the key and the applicable brand as the value.

```
keywords = {"M3": "BMW",
              "Prius": "Toyota",
              "Focus": "Ford"}
```

Using the code below works for many cases, however, if there are two matches in the same row, the returned value is NAN.

```
df["searchBrand"]=['text'].str.findall("|".join(keywords.keys())).str.join(",").map(keywords)
```

For example, this is what I get, but it's not what I'm looking for:

| text | searchBrand |
| --- | --- |
| The M3 is quick! | BMW |
| Some would say the Prius is economical, but others like the M3 for its speed | nan |
| Who likes the focus? | Ford |

Thank you in advance

Comment: What should be the result if there are two or more matches?

Comment: If there are two or more matches, I would be fine with 1) return just the first match or b) return both matches in the same column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) for getting the first match:

```py
>>> df
                                                text
0                                   The M3 is quick!
1  Some would say the Prius is economical, but ot...
2                               Who likes the Focus?
>>> 
>>> df['searchBrand'] = df['text'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(keywords.keys())})', expand=False).map(keywords)
>>> df
                                                text searchBrand
0                                   The M3 is quick!         BMW
1  Some would say the Prius is economical, but ot...      Toyota
2                               Who likes the Focus?        Ford
```

In the above, I have changed `Who likes the focus?` to `Who likes the Focus?`. If that's not a typo in the question, you can try:

```py
>>> df["searchBrand"] = df['text'].str.title().str.extract(f'({"|".join(keywords.keys())})', expand=False).map(keywords)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Nikolaos. I'm actually getting a syntax error between the single quote and comma in the str.extract() call, before the expand parameter. I've looked up the str.extract documentation and there isn't anything obvious that would return a SyntaxError. Any thoughts? Thanks again